# eclipse php server path problem

Tags: php, eclipse

I created a php project "testphp" and add a helloworld.php page, and run it within eclipse with url http://localhost/testphp/helloworld.php, it is not working, I got 404 error. I am using windows7, IIS7, I can run php pages very will with my browsers. So, looks like the IIS7 server cannot find my project, and the helloworld.php, I suppose eclipse will automatically put the php files under the wwwroot directory?

Comment: It is not clear for me: On the same computer where you have installed Eclipse, do you get a webpage with a regular browser or also a 404 error?

Comment: well, if only I put the php file in the wwwroot directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you have a mix up with a couple things here, I believe. Eclipse does not replace nor updates nor configures anything with your server setup. Whatever you setup as your "project" in Ecplise is only known to Eclipse. Hence, you can call your project and (not entirely true but) more or less the directory structure, where and however you want. Your project "testphp" is a thing between you and Ecplise--not IIS7. IIS7 has no knowledge of Ecplipse and only cares about what is in its wwwroot directory.